# scalaj etag get can't parse

Tags: scala, etag, if-none-match

Using [scalaj.http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http) 2.4 I cannot get the correct code for a `If-None-Match` etag for this simple call:

```
import scalaj.http.Http
object EtagTest extends App {
  val firstResponse = Http("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs")
  // get correct etag ...
  val response = Http("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs").header("If-None-Match", "\"98f0c1b396a4e5d54f4d5fe561d54b44\"").asString
  println(response.code)
}
```

I'm expecting a `304 Not Modified` but I get a `200`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked for me. It looks like the `ETag` you get with this program is not the `ETag` you've hard coded in your program. The strange thing is that when I send a cURL request to it, the `ETag` returned is the one you have hard coded.

```
import scalaj.http.Http

object ETagTest extends App {
  val firstResponse = Http("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs").asString
  val response = Http("https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs").header("If-None-Match", firstResponse.header(key = "ETag").get).asString
  println(response.code)
  println(response.header(key = "ETag").get)
}
```

Output of the above:

```
304
"80b190627d4c87e9a37c34e20ea246a1"
```